# Declaring a type (enum, struct etc.) in class definition increase code size

Tags: c++, armcc

I am developing some embedded software with **armcc** compiler. For debugging purposes optimizations are kept at minimum wiht *-O0* flag. In order to improve code clarity I have **moved some enum and struct definitions into a class with public access.**

From this:

```
enum A{
 a,
 b,
 c,
 d
};

struct C{
 int q;
 int w;
 int e;
};

class myClass{

....
};
```

To this:

```
class myClass{
 public:
    enum A{
     a,
     b,
     c,
     d
    };

    struct C{
     int q;
     int w;
     int e;
    };
....
};
```

And reaching them through myClass like;

```
myClass::C new_struct;
new_struct.q= myClass::a;
```

But to my surprise even with no other difference in code it increased the code size like 600 bytes. I assume that it is caused by compiler optimizations (even at -O0 there are some optimizations active) of replacing enumerations with direct values but not sure about this. What may have caused the increase in code size (or prevented optimization if it is the case)?

Comment: member variables(Predefined or user defined) will be allocated every time when a instance of class will be created...

Comment: try a diff on the assembly

Comment: I did not declare additional variables. Just the definitions are moved into the class.

Comment: I'm sorry for a dumb question, but you stripped the debug data from the image before measuring its size, right? ([link to an explanation on how to do it, in case you didn't](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0483c/BABJBIHI.html))

Comment: @dasblinkenlight For both builds there are debug data embedded into elf.

Comment: @Faruxx So that's your explanation right there: debug symbols become longer, because what used to be called `A::a` is now called `myClass::A::a`, what used to be `A::b` is `myClass::A::b` now, and so on. All these longer strings take additional space, making the image larger. Stripping the debug symbols should make the two codes produce images of identical size.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that perfectly makes sense. Thanks. But there is a problem that i cannot repeat the process. I have checked out to previous version and compiling but size doesn't reduce back. (Probably because of not version controlled files in git.) So i cannot verify your answer. But if you convert your comment into answer i would happily upvote.

Comment: For your next project, I suggest you invest in a keyboard with a semicolon key. C++ ain't Java!

Comment: @TonyK thank for advice. In the hurry of asking question I may have left out couple of details. But from the question you should have understand that I can successfully compile the code. So may to your surprise I have a keyboard with semicolon. Also I am familiar with there are no 4 following dots in C++ in case this may be your next argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For both builds there are debug data embedded into elf.

Debug symbol table included in the image contains information about each item defined in your program. When you move an `enum` and a `struct` inside a class, the names related to elements of the `enum` and the `struct` become larger: `A::a` becomes `myClass::A::a`, `A::b` becomes `myClass::A::b`, and so on. All these longer strings take additional space in the image file, making it larger.

[Stripping the debug symbols](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0483c/BABJBIHI.html) should make the two codes produce images of identical size.

Answer (score 3):

C++ name mangling will be different with structs and enum declared into the class.
This would happen for example if your class has methods with struct C in the argument list.
A quick test using gcc shows that a method:
`void func( struct C *) ;`
would be called `_ZN7myClass4funcEPNS_1CE` when struct are declared in the class and `_ZN7myClass4funcEP1C` if the struct is declared outside of the class.
I don't have armcc to test with but I would believe it behaves the same.